# Can't pass parameter when creating an instance of a class

Tags: python, class

I don't understand why when trying to create an instance of the class 'Deck', PyCharm returns an error that 'Deck is not callable.

**Main.py**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

while play_again is True:
    player_count: int = int(input("Enter number of players: "))
    print(player_count)

    game_deck: Deck = Deck("game") #error on this line
    shuffle(game_deck)
    burn_deck = Deck
```

---

**Deck.py**

```
class Deck:

card_sequence: Card = []
deck_type = ""

def __init__(self, deck_type):
    card_suits = ['Clubs', 'Diamonds', 'Hearts', 'Spades']
    card_ranks = ['Ace', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', 'Jack', 'Queen', 'King']
    self.deck_type = deck_type
    if self.deck_type == "player":
        for i in range(2):
            self.card_sequence = [random.random() for _ in range(2)]
    elif self.deck_type == "game":
        for i in card_suits:
            for j in card_ranks:
                new_card = Card(i, j)
        self.card_sequence.push(new_card)

        for _ in self.card_sequence:
            self.card_sequence.append(random.random())
    elif self.deck_type == "burn":
        self.size = 0
        self.card_sequence = []
```

---

**Error**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Chris/PycharmProjects/BlackJack/Main.py", line 36, in <module>
    game_deck: Deck = Deck("game")
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: _Did you import your module?_ from Deck import Deck  _Did you create an object?_ deck = Deck()

Comment: @SamrajM I had 'import Deck', but changed it to your suggestion 'from Deck import Deck'. Thanks for the help! If you would like to add an answer to this question I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import your module and create an object as either:

```
from Deck import Deck
deck = Deck()
```

or

```
import Deck
deck = Deck.Deck()
```